# How can I completely uninstall DisplayLink?

Tags: macos

Once upon a time, I installed `DisplayLink` but have since uninstalled it. I have another program on my computer that keeps crashing and upon looking at the logs, it seems to be an issue with the `DisplayLinkManager`.

```
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.displaylink.displaylinkmanager[24073]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.displaylink.displaylinkmanager): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 5 seconds.
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on awdl0
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook ReportCrash[24057]: Attempt to read info_array in pid 24073 failed, address was 7fff611746e8
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook ReportCrash[24057]: Attempt to read info_array in pid -1 failed, address was 7fff611746e8
Nov 12 00:28:31 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook ReportCrash[24057]: Attempt to read info_array in pid 24073 failed, address was 7fff611746e8
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook ReportCrash[24057]: Attempt to read info_array in pid -1 failed, address was 7fff611746e8
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook ReportCrash[24057]: Saved crash report for DisplayLinkManager[24073] version ??? to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/DisplayLinkManager_2015-11-12-002831_MoonBook.crash
Nov 12 00:28:31 MoonBook ReportCrash[24057]: Removing excessive log: file:///Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/DisplayLinkManager_2015-11-11-221429_MoonBook.crash
```

So there appear to be some remnants left, but when I search for `DisplayLink` in Spotlight, I get no results (just links to Wikipedia, etc). So how can I completely remove `com.displaylink.displaylinkmanager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Terminal, run `locate displaylinkmanager` and you should get a list with all files containing "displaylinkmanager".

Then run `rm file`, replace file with each file from the previous command. This will delete the files, and hopefully fix the confusion that causes your program to crash.

Answer (score 10):

From version 1.1 on, the uninstaller is only included with the login screen extension. You can download it using the link in the dropdown box that appears when you click the DisplayLink icon in the menu bar, or use [this direct link](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos_extension).

[image: DisplayLink manager panel showing login screen extension download button]

An uninstaller is included on the downloaded DMG.

[image: DisplayLink login extension DMG contents]

Comment: This is what worked for me in MacOS Big Sur. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Just download app again from this link, open the installer file, then select uninstall from there :)
http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/osx

Comment: This seems to not working as of version 1.1 - it just says 'a newer version is already installed'.

Comment: This worked for me, I downloaded the drivers not the manager, the link that says "DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for macOS" and on that image there is a uninstaller I used that and Displaylink Manager was uninstalled! hope this helps to others...

Answer (score 1):

The displaylink-debian.sh (in my case) lives in /usr/bin

sudo displaylink-debian.sh uninstall and follow the instructions. All those having issues with "Missing component: Linux headers for running kernel, 4.9.0-6-amd64." should use this as well, you will receive the same error but it appears to continue with the uninstall to completion.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  One key point to keep in mind is that macOS != Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just quit DisplayLink Manager from the tray icon. Then go to your Applications folder in Finder and move the DisplayLink Manager to the Trash.